# Mongoosejs:-copy data from one Mongodb collection to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi I am a newbie working on node and mongobd

I have created a schema in server.js with mongoose :

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
  password: String,
  facebook: String,
  google: String,
  origin: {city: String, state: String},
  destination: {city: String, state: String},
  price: Array,
  time: Date,
  phone_no: String,
  tokens: Array,
  type: String,
  profile: {
    name: { type: String, default: '' },
    gender: { type: String, default: '' },
    location: { type: String, default: '' },
    website: { type: String, default: '' },
    picture: { type: String, default: '' }
  },

  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordExpires: Date
});
```

Now I have implemented a feature where a user signs in gmail.
As soon as he does that he is redirected to home page.

This is the use of my collection with the help of passport:-

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(facebook, function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  if (req.user) {
    User.findOne({ facebook: profile.id }, function(err, existingUser) {
      if (existingUser) {
        req.flash('errors', { msg: 'There is already a Facebook account that belongs to you. Sign in with that account or delete it, then link it with your current account.' });
        done(err);
      } else {
        User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, user) {
          user.facebook = profile.id;
          user.tokens.push({ kind: 'facebook', accessToken: accessToken });
          user.profile.name = user.profile.name || profile.displayName;
          user.profile.gender = user.profile.gender || profile._json.gender;
          user.profile.picture = user.profile.picture || 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + profile.id + '/picture?type=large';
          user.save(function(err) {
            console.log('Facebook account has been linked.');
            done(err, user);
          });
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    User.findOne({ facebook: profile.id }, function(err, existingUser) {
      if (existingUser) return done(null, existingUser);
      User.findOne({ email: profile._json.email }, function(err, existingEmailUser) {
        if (existingEmailUser) {
          req.flash('errors', { msg: 'There is already an account using this email address. Sign in to that account and link it with Facebook manually from Account Settings.' });
          done(err);
        } else {
          var user = new User();
          user.email = profile._json.email;
          user.facebook = profile.id;
          user.tokens.push({ kind: 'facebook', accessToken: accessToken });
          user.profile.name = profile.displayName;
          user.profile.gender = profile._json.gender;
          user.profile.picture = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + profile.id + '/picture?type=large';
          user.profile.location = (profile._json.location) ? profile._json.location.name : '';
          user.save(function(err) {
            done(err, user);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
}));
```

Now his credentials is saved in the database in the profile field.

I want some of his information to be put in another collection..ie his username etc.

Is it possible to do so.Please help me out.I dont know how to do in mongo

Comment: Can you post your code where you use your current collection? So we can give you the needed hints to complete it

Comment: Before I post the answer, can I ask why you want copy data in multiple collections? This is not too much logic, you should query the first collection to get that data instead saving them in another one. And what about when you need to update that data? You need to update multiple collections. Wrong way imho.

Comment: @michelem a common use case for this 'denormalization' is to avoid two calls to the database, e.g. you might want to attach the userid, name, and avatar to each Comment object. sure, if a username changes, you now have to change it in more than one place, but for a high volume app the tradeoff might be worth it. one situation where you frequently do this is a Cassandra schema

Comment: @Michelem I want to do so because i want to keep some of the fields of data confidential and not reveal it to others in my company..Also can just fetch the user as well as other information from one collection instead  of two or three

Comment: @plato spot on with your analysis

Comment: @PrathameshP do you know you can have multiple routes displaying different data from the same collection? I mean, you can query for only `username` or for everything and give the queries different route (ie: `/users` and `/admin/users`). @Plato I know but I don't think this is the case.